# Retrieve content from parsed json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following code that I need to be able to get each section of the array separately.

Here is the code:

```
$parsed = $parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'];
foreach($parsed as $key => $value)
    {
            echo '<table border="1" width="200px">';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<td><b>' . $value['title'] . '</td></font>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<tr>' .$value['fcttext'] . '</tr></font>';
            echo '<td><img src=' . $value['icon_url'] . '></td>';
            echo '</tr></table>';
    }
```

What I want is to be able to get lets say the first title in the array

```
echo $value['title'][1]
```

The above is what i thought would work.  But it returns just a single letter.

It should read "Saturday"

How can i go about getting it corrected?

Comment: The reason it returns a single letter is that `$value['title']` is a string - not an array. So when referencing element 1 you actually get the second letter of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$parsed[0]['title'];` will return the first item of the array's title.

Indexing starts with `0` and not `1` (so 0 is first, 1 is second etc) - saving those bytes adds up on large projects!

As @JimL indicates, `[1]` gets the second item of our variable. If it's an array this is the second item of the array. As this is a string (the `title`) we get the second letter instead. Hope that explains it for you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped. Please mark up and accept to help others who may come by here! :)